# How to use .replace in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some Javascript I am using on my site that automatically generates breadcrumbs based on my file structor. The problem I am having is that the names it displays are based on the file names, and some times those names have under scores in them. here is an example:

Home / Marketing / News_events / News & Events Home Page

What I would like to do is remove the under score in News_events and replace it with a space... same with all the bread crumbs on the site.

My Java Script is not very good but I think I have to add something like this:

```js
string.replace(/_/g,' ');
```

I'm just not sure where or how to place it with in the Javascript.

Here is the full Javascript:

```js
 
  function breadcrumbs(){
  sURL = new String;
  bits = new Object;
  var x = 0;
  var stop = 0;
  var output = '<a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a> &nbsp;/&nbsp; '; 
  sURL = location.href;
  sURL = sURL.slice(8,sURL.length); 
  chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
  sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length)
  while(!stop){
    chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
    if (chunkStart != -1){
      bits[x] = sURL.slice(0,chunkStart)
      sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length);
    }else{
      stop = 1;
    }
    x++;
  }
  for(var i in bits){
    output += "<a href=\"";
    for(y=1;y<x-i;y++){
      output += "../";
    }
    output += bits[i] + "/\">" + bits[i] + "</a> &nbsp;/&nbsp; ";
  }
  document.write(output + document.title);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me but you need to use what `replace` returns: `string  = string.replace(/_/g,' ');`

Comment: for a single char replacement, why use a regex? `.replace('_', ' ')` would be far more efficient.

Comment: @MarcB without the global tag, it will only replace the first instance. You need to use regex to replace all of the instances in the string.

Comment: @MarcB if the OP didnt state it would be used once, its better to assume there is an unknown amount of characters needing a replacement, to avoid the follow up question of "Why is my .replace only replacing a value once"

Comment: How and where do I put it in the Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace this line, so that `bits[i]` has the underscores replaced:

`output += bits[i] + "/\">" + bits[i] + "</a> &nbsp;/&nbsp; ";`

Turns into:

`output += bits[i] + "/\">" + bits[i].replace(/_/g,' ') + "</a> &nbsp;/&nbsp; ";`

Comment: That did it!!!! Thank you very much! It wont let me accept your answer for a couple of min.